# Install linux on a usb without rebooting

Tags: system-installation, live-usb, manjaro

What options do I have if I'd like to install [manjaro](http://manjaro.org/) on my usb-stick without having to reboot my maschine.
In that manner I can do my work while Linux installes. And when the installation is finished I'd boot that OS on the Stick with VirtualBox as I found a howto [here](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/boot-a-usb-flash-drive-in-virtualbox/).

*I need to have that OS on a stick, so that I can use to boot that OS on other machines to fix stuff.*

Comment: Eh? You need a working machine to create a live usb

Comment: Set up USB passthrough on VirtualBox and install to the USB stick from VirtualBox. There is no need to use your host system in the process, therefore no need to reboot it.

Comment: Why would you ever need to reboot system to make a usb drive bootable?

Comment: @RegisteredUser because I wanted to install Linux ON a USB. Not FROM a USB.